# How to add a timer - Visual Studio, XNA (C#)

Tags: xna, c#

I'm wanting to add a timer in an XNA game using C#. The ultimate goal is to increment a score in a game every second by 10 points. As of now the score stays at zero. Watching YouTube videos is proving to be counter productive as they're quite confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Show code of what you have tried up to now.

Answer (score 3):

I believe something like this should work. (Place the code in the Update block)

```
Timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds; // Increment the timer by the elapsed game time.

if (Timer >= 1000) // Check to see if one second has passed.
{
    Points += 10; // Increment the points by 10.
    Timer -= 1000; // Reset the timer.
}
```

Comment: Note that `Timer` is a number, not an instance of special class.